# Drools rule multiple objects with multiple constraints

Tags: drools, rule-engine, drools-guvnor

I have following rule

```
rule "Row LoanApproval"
dialect "mvel"
when
    f2 : Loan( amount >= 0 )
    f1 : Applicant( creditScore <= 200 )
then
    f2.setApproved( true );
    System.out.println("rule call");
end
```

My problem is value of field "approved" will be true when amount>=0. Second constraint f1 : Applicant( creditScore <= 200 ) plays no role here.
so how can I write it when both conditions are true. then "approved" should be true?

Comment: In your example, both conditions in the left hand side (Loan and Applicant) must be true in order for the right hand side to be executed. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: that's the problem. both conditions are not true. still right hand side gets executed. may be this is because stateless or stateful kie session. which I didn't get that.

Comment: The type of session has nothing to do here. What are the objects you are inserting into your session?

Comment: <batch-execution>
  <insert out-identifier="applicant">
    <com.rup.lk.Applicant>
      <age>1</age>
      <creditScore>230</creditScore>
    </com.rup.lk.Applicant>
  </insert>
  <insert out-identifier="loan">
    <com.rup.lk.Loan>
   <amount>1239</amount>
    </com.rup.lk.Loan>
  <fire-all-rules />
</batch-execution>
this is the xmlrequest.

Comment: That seems odd to me. Have you tried to print out `f1` and `f1.getCreditScore()` in the right hand side of your rule?

Comment: I got it working. it was because of stateful kie session.